# KODI is the only program i can run

Tags: desktop, startup, show-desktop

I had KODI configured to start automatically while running the beta.  I upgraded to the released version (sudo apt-get update, upgrade and then dist-upgrade).
It seemed to run successfully and KODI still runs at startup.

But now, when I exit Kodi, i get logged off and can only log back in to a Kodi.  There is a gear shift where I can select to log in to Pantheon but it does nothing...   I cannot get back to the desktop.

What have I done to myself?   Is there a way from command line (via putty) to re-setup Elementary?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Log out.

While you're in a login screen, you'll see a small gear icon next to your user name. Click on it and switch the desktop environment to Pantheon. Everything will work as expected.

You didn't mess anything up. You have just selected Kodi as your default desktop environment.